# Why did the Vanyar leave Tirion for Taniquetil?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

It is stated that once the Calaquendi Elves got to Valinor from their Great Journey from Middle-earth, both the Noldor and Vanyar built and resided in the city of Tirion on Tuna. Later on the Vanyar abandoned Tirion on Tuna and moved to the mountain of Taniquetil.

My question is: Why would the Vanyar leave a city they built to live at the base of Mount Taniquetil?

Comment: It certainly was an upgrade...

Comment: From the perspective of the story, it means they are not around to speak against Feanor or assist the Teleri.

Answer (score 10):

## They grew to love Aman and the light of the Trees

As detailed in *The Silmarillion*, the Vanyar had an awing for the Two Trees and the lands of the Valar. This combined with their grace in the eyes of Manwë and Yavanna led them to forsake the city of Tirion and move to Taniquetil

> **As the ages passed the Vanyar grew to love the land of the Valar and the full light of the Trees**, and they forsook the city of Tirion upon Túna, and dwelt thereafter upon the mountain of Manwë, or about the plains and woods of Valinor, and became sundered from the Noldor.
> <sub>The Silmarillion - Chapter 5: Of Eldamar and the Princes of the Eldalië</sub>

> The Vanyar indeed held [Melkor] in suspicion, **for they dwelt in the light of the Trees and were content**
> <sub>ibid - Chapter 6: Of Fëanor and the Unchaining of Melkor</sub>

Answer (score 3):

They lived with the Noldor in Tirion on Tuna for a time, but

> As the ages passed the Vanyar grew to love the land of the Valar and the full light of the Trees, and they forsook the city of Tirion upon Tuna, and dwelt thereafter upon the mountain of Manwe, or about the plains and woods of Valinor, and became sundered from the Noldor.

it was also noted that

> Manwe and Varda loved most the Vanyar, the Fair Elves

so it was natural for them to live near Taniquetil.

-- quotes from *The Silmarillion*